# Rails - how to add parameter to the "params.require(:model).permit" construction?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, slug

I have following code in the controller:

```
def create
    @company = Company.new(company_params)
    ....
end
private
    def company_params
      params.require(:company).permit(...list of columns...).merge(latlng: geocode)
    end
```

I would need to save to the database the column called **slug**. The value of this column would be

```
slug = params[:company][:name].parameterize
```

The column slug is not mentioned in the **permit** list. How to add & save this information to the database?

Thanks

Comment: BTW, if you know, you need to save the value of that parameter, why not then editing the *permit* list itself ?

Comment: Doesn't just adding a line `@company.slug = params[:company][:name].parameterize` do the trick?

Comment: Don't forget to index the `slug` column.

Answer (score 0):

```rb
def blog_post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :author, :published, :body)
end
```